# Run program from windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a program that is stored in program files folder.

I created windows service to run it, but when I do, it doesn't start.

I used process monitor to see what happens, and realized that it's looking for all dependencies in system32 folder.

If I take the program, with all referenced dependencies and paste them into the root of system32 folder, it works! But I don't like it that way, I want to run it from specific folder.

Comment: Paste the code that you are using this way we can better understand where the issues may reside..

Comment: What does the event log say when you try to run the app? ... that might help someone solve the issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PATH trick didn't work. It gave me error about some depended file software were trying to locate. But I found the solution. You can provide working directory:

process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory

That did the trick. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Add your program's folder to PATH environment variable and your service will find it there...